# Expression for the real 7/3 power

Tags: functions

I need an expression for the real 7/3 power of a real-valued function, i.e., a reformulation of

```
f[x_] := g[x]^(7/3)
```

that works for negative values of `g[x]`. This function and its first and second derivatives are used in heavy computation (i.e. in objectives to `FindMinimum`) and need to be well-defined at all values of `x`. In particular, I've tried the following, which don't work:

```
f[x_] := g[x]^(7/3)
```

which gives complex values at negative values of `g[x]`, and

```
f[x_] := Surd[g[x],3]^7
```

which gives a "Infinite expression" error when its derivative is evaluated at 0.

Comment: (-1)^(7/3) == ???

Comment: @belisarius I'm sure he's interpreting this as -1 and that's rather the point of the new `CubeRoot` and `Surd` functions.

Comment: Why doesn't `f[x_] := Piecewise[{{g[x]^(7/3), g[x] >= 0}}, -(-g[x])^(7/3)]` work?

Comment: @belisarius I want the *real* 7/3 power of a real number, which is well defined over all $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I will try that.

Answer (score 3):

To some extent, this is understandable given the formula for the derivative of the `Surd`.

```
D[Surd[x^4, 3], x] // InputForm
(* Out: (4*x^3)/(3*Surd[x^4, 3]^2) *)
```

Of course, this formula is good, *except* when $x=0$.  Computer algebra systems frequently return this type of "generic" result.  If you really need to work at zero, perhaps something like the following will work:

```
Clear[f, fp];
f[x_] = CubeRoot[x^7];
fp[x_] := f'[x] /; x != 0;
fp[0] = fp[0.0] = 0;
```

This should define a function `fp` representing your derivative that *might* work as expected.  It also might depend on what you need to do with it.

Comment: $f$ is used as input to functionals in my code that themselves take `D` of it, so if possible I would like to avoid having to define the derivative of `f` specially.

Comment: (Also, I suppose I hoped Mathematica would be "smart" enough to take a limit at 0, instead of throwing up its hands and aborting with an error.)

Comment: If I define the function just as f[x_] := Surd[x, 3]^7 and then make this: Plot[Evaluate[D[f[x], x]], {x, -1, 1}] it returns a plot. However, if I define it like this: f[x_] = D[Surd[x, 3]^7, x] /; x != 0; and try to draw the same plot or the one with the exclusion: Plot[Evaluate[f[x]], {x, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> x == 0] it returns nothing at all. Do you know why?

Comment: @Alexei It is semantically meaningless. Test it yourself by plugging in some particular arguments, as in `f[1]`.  Remove the `/; x!= 0` codicil and you might be more successful.

Comment: @whuber. Thank you. In fact I started my question with that.  I tried your test as well and see what happens, but I seem to not understand its origin. Where is the difference between the operator written in the answer above and the one I wrote? I seem to only combined the second and third lines from that answer in one statement. The result is, however, clearly not what I expected, meaning that I am missing something important.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch One clear difference is that you're using `D` while I'm using `Derivative`, as expressed via the prime symbol.  `Derivative` operates on a function and you can then plug in a symbol `x` or a number.  `D` operates on expressions and when you define `f[x_] := D[thing,x]` you run into a problem when `x` is set to a number.

Comment: @MarK McClure Thank you